# How do I get a specific Activity to show up in a Scrollable Tabs?

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

**So, I've started experimenting** with the Scrollable Tabs + Swipe navigation type. 
I managed to change what activity to inflate, but the same activity is being shown on all the tabs.

How do I make it so that there's a different activity on each of the tabs? I'm a **newbie** at Android development, so please explain it easy.

**I am using the default template that's included in eclipse.**

Thanks in advance!

The MainActivity.java:

```
package com.heavyfork.slidetest;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 8;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.preparations).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();

        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_picture_display,
                container, false);


        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a newbie, so I'll try to explain how the sample project works.
First of all, you talk about Activity, but you need to use Fragment. The activity is just the host for one or more fragments.

The activity diplays only a ViewPager which is used to display some Fragment (or a View) and enable swiping from one to another. 
The SectionsPagerAdapter works like all Adapter objects in Android, you create one, you give it some data  (ie : ArrayList of country), you implement some methods including the getView or in this case getItem method. In these method you are given the position in the ViewPager, so you can access the right data and give it to your Fragment via a Bundle object (it's done in this example, the position +1).

To give data, use this :

```
            VisuFragment fragment = new VisuFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("id", id);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
```

And to get it from the onCreate method of the Fragment :

```
            int id = getArguments().getInt("id");
```

The ViewPager and the Adpater will manage everything on the screen, it will ask for new Fragment and delete old ones without you knowing.

For the sample code, if you want to see something different on each page, delete the all content of the onCreateView method and put this :

```
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText("This is fragment number : "+getArguments().getInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            return tv;
```